# Using PostGIS to compute graph data

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgis, graph

I have a query which return me two dimension data:

```
SELECT POINT(value , extract(EPOCH FROM datetime)) AS pseudo_geom
FROM table
```

gaves me

```
pseudo_geom
---------------
(18,1439679940)
(29,1439680000)
(16,1439680060)
```

What I would like to do is to convert these data into a `path` type to be able to simplificate through ST_Simplify which accept a geometry type.

My goal is actually to reduce the number of points to display on a graph.

I tried with the path function and playing around with point(), string_agg() and grouping my data, with no result...

What could be the easiest and shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this using this scheme (not as simple as firstly expected):

```
SELECT ST_X(geom) as value, ST_Y(geom) as datetime from (
    select (ST_DumpPoints(simplifiedLine)).* as g1 from (
        SELECT ST_Simplify(ST_MakeLine(the_geom.resulted), 15) as simplifiedLine FROM (
            SELECT ST_MakePoint(value, extract(EPOCH FROM datetime)) as resulted FROM table 
            ORDER BY datetime ASC
        ) as the_geom
    ) as g   
) as pt
```

Hope that will help others.

Answer (score 0):

In PostGIS a `path` is called `line`.

You can use [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) to conncat your points to a line. So extend your query with somthinge like:

```
SELECT ST_Simplify(ST_MakeLine(POINT(value , extract(EPOCH FROM datetime)))) AS simplified_line
FROM table;
```

You should consider to define an `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the track with ST_MakeLine! However I got `Error: the function st_makeline(point) does not exists.